# Bibliography out of bound

Tags: ieeetran, ieeeconf

I'm writing an article that is supposed to be written using the IEEE Manuscript Templates for Conference Proceedings. I put all my references in a ref.bib to manage them easily. After compiling, (I use TeXnicCenter so it also compiles the .bib automatically using bibtex) I get the last two columns (the one containing bibliography) to be out of bound.
It says in the log:

> ** Conference Paper **
>   Before submitting the final camera ready copy, remember to:
>
> 1. Manually equalize the lengths of two columns on the last page
>      of your paper;
> 2. Ensure that any PostScript and/or PDF output post-processing
>      uses only Type 1 fonts and that every step in the generation
>      process uses the appropriate paper size.

Here's a snip of what it looks like:
[image: display]
This is the skeleton of my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\title{title}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{adress}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
abstract goes here
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

\section{chapter 1}

\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.

\section*{Acknowledgment}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}  
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

I used `\notice{*}` to include all references without citing them in the body.

Is there anyway to quickly solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your code so that we can compile it to reproduce a minimal version of the problem. I can't compile your code as I don't have `ref.bib`.

Comment: Could be that bib entry 8 or 9 is the culprit. Can you add them to your question please?

Comment: I would remove the URL from that entry. Because first it's on RG which can be googled easily and second it's not the official copy. On another note, use `ieeeconf` as you have tagged but not the `conference` mode of `ieeetran`

Comment: Please edit your query to post the contents of `ref.bib`.